# Convergence of Number of Success in Bernoulli Trials

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

Assume the probability of success in the Bernoulli trial is $p$ with $0\leq p \leq 1$, let $S_n$ be the number of  success in $n$ trials, determine whether $S_n/n$ converges.

So I know how to determine whether a random sequence, but I do not fully understand the model in this problem. $S_n$ could be from $1-n$. Is $S_n$ the summation of $X_1$ to $X_n$ , where $X_i$ represents the $i$th success in $n$ trial. Could anyone explain the random sequence of this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $S_n =\sum\limits_1^n X_i$ could be from $0$ to $n$.  The sequence is $S_1,\frac12S_2,\frac13S_3,\ldots$.  You are looking at the law of large numbers

Comment: @Henry I see, thanks!